# Azure Web role with Multiple services

Tags: wcf, azure, webrole

I have a Azure web role WCF service  deployed that has 3 services in it.

However, when I try to get add service references for the 3 services in my client app, only 1 service gets the populated correctly.

There are no interfaces accessible for the other two service references. Is it not possible to create a WCF service webrole that has multiple services?

Jas

Comment: are there 3 distinct .svc (services) or are there 3 methods in one service?

Comment: there are 3 distinct svc files in the project.

Comment: Not sure what the deal is... seems to work from a fresh project. So will debug my way through this sat night... I'm such a geek